# Programming tests

Tags: c++

I seeking a web site for programming skills testing. Maybe free analogue of codility or something like when you get a task, and need to upload a correct answer code, solving the task. Namely i interested in c++. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**your answer is that you should try your self more!**
But some goods:
the ACM site: http://icpc.baylor.edu
http://acm.uva.es/contest/
http://www.codeforces.com
http://code.google.com/codejam/
and also
http://www0.us.ioccc.org/index.html
http://www.mycplus.com/featured-articles/programming-contests-and-challenges/